# Initializers Type Cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializer

Tags: swift

i am having the above problem as mention in title  this porgram is for IOS 8.2  as target 
but when i use it in  mine Xcode it shows the Error As there target is 8.0
please thanks in Advance :)

mine Code is Given Below and i need it for target 8.0

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

let kGeotificationLatitudeKey = "latitude"
let kGeotificationLongitudeKey = "longitude"
let kGeotificationRadiusKey = "radius"
let kGeotificationIdentifierKey = "identifier"
let kGeotificationNoteKey = "note"
let kGeotificationEventTypeKey = "eventType"

enum EventType: Int {
 case OnEntry = 0
 case OnExit = 1
}

class Geotification: NSObject, NSCoding, MKAnnotation {
 var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
 var radius: CLLocationDistance
 var identifier: String
 var note: String
 var eventType: EventType

 var title: String {
  if note.isEmpty {
   return "No Note"
  }
  return note
 }

 var subtitle: String {
  var eventTypeString = eventType == .OnEntry ? "On Entry" : "On Exit"
  return "Radius: \(radius)m - \(eventTypeString)"
 }

 init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance,             identifier: String, note: String, eventType: EventType) {
  self.coordinate = coordinate
  self.radius = radius
  self.identifier = identifier
  self.note = note
  self.eventType = eventType
 }

 // MARK: NSCoding

 required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
  let latitude = decoder.decodeDoubleForKey(kGeotificationLatitudeKey)
  let longitude = decoder.decodeDoubleForKey(kGeotificationLongitudeKey)
  coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude:       longitude)
  radius = decoder.decodeDoubleForKey(kGeotificationRadiusKey)
  identifier = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(kGeotificationIdentifierKey) as  String
  note = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(kGeotificationNoteKey) as String
  eventType =         EventType(decoder.decodeIntegerForKey(kGeotificationEventTypeKey))

 }

 func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
  coder.encodeDouble(coordinate.latitude, forKey: kGeotificationLatitudeKey)
  coder.encodeDouble(coordinate.longitude, forKey: kGeotificationLongitudeKey)
    coder.encodeDouble(radius, forKey: kGeotificationRadiusKey)
    coder.encodeObject(identifier, forKey: kGeotificationIdentifierKey)
    coder.encodeObject(note, forKey: kGeotificationNoteKey)
    coder.encodeInt(Int32(eventType.rawValue, forKey:     kGeotificationEventTypeKey))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1-) Choose your project root on the left panel

2-) In General -> Deployment Info window you can set your target.[image]

Comment: Ö i did this .... yes i did this after doing .... target as 8.0 it is showing these error 
above code is a target  of 8.2 
but somewhere in initializers it is showing errors

Comment: do you use PodFile in your project?

Answer (score 0):

bro you have updated your Xcode and using the code with of previous IOS versions. you should search how to initialise these vars in 8.2 ..